# How to debug and log helper functions in docpad.coffee?

Tags: docpad

Trying to add new helpers to `docpad.coffee` I'd like to debug these.
Having setup node inspector as outlined in http://docpad.org/docs/debug I expected the console to show logs when used with e.g.

```
getOutDir: (inPath) ->
    console.log('inPath')
```

How to set breakpoints to helper methods in docpad.coffee?
How to log from docpad.coffee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions on docpad.org for node-inspector are incorrect (they are being worked on).  You can't just run `docpad-debug` because that runs the globally installed version of docpad which confuses the debugger.  Instead run the local copy of docpad-debug from your node-modules folder:

```
./node_modules/.bin/docpad-debug run
```

Comment: Debugging instructions have now been updated in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: you may need `.\node_modules\.bin\docpad-debug run` to get it working in Windows

Answer (score 1):

> How to log from docpad.coffee?

```
docpad.log("info", "... your log info here ...")
```

Other log levels are "warn" and "error".

Comment: Still, the question on breakpoints in node inspector remains :)